# Trying to add a select element

Tags: jquery, html, bookmarklet

I'm trying to add `<select>` inside a specific div that has a class that is shared by 3 divs. This is the code

```
<div id="producer_section_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_" class="section_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_ last_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_">
    <div class="field-row_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_">
        <fieldset>

            <span id="producer-name" class="input_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_"></span>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="field-row_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="producer-number">Producer Number</label>
            <span id="producer-number" class="input_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_">623886</span>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="field-row_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="producer-phone">Phone Number</label>
            <span id="producer-phone" class="input_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_">(888) 407-7044</span>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="field-row_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_ last_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="producer-email">Email Address</label>
            <span id="producer-email" class="input_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_">MEDICARE@EHEALTHINSURANCE.COM</span>
        </fieldset>
    </div>


</div>
```

Specifically the last row of producer email. 
Here is the code that im trying to use right now.

```
var addSelect = "<select>
Checkcheck</select>";

$('#producer_section_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_ .field-row_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_last_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_' ).append(addSelect);
```

Comment: "an id that is shared by 3 divs" please fix this, it gives me the Jibblies. :3

Comment: Like, change the Id of that? wish i could. I wouldn't have this problem if the programmer didn't reuse names. I don't have access to the source so all i can do to make my life easier is make quality of life changes with an extension i'm making. I'm actually an underwriter lol

Comment: Oh, I see; I thought you were referring to the 3 divs shown in your code with the same CLASSES, so it would be a typo.

Comment: You can't have a newline in a string literal. Is `addSelect` really defined like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely, that last element actually has two classes and not one. That is why your selector is not working.

Also, apparently, these classes are probably automatically generated so I wouldn't depend on them.

Maybe targeting the `producer-email` span then querying for it's parent would be a better approach.

Something like (untested):

```
$('#producer-email').parent().append(addSelect);
```

EDIT:

To target the parent `div` and not the `fieldset`, like you wanted, you can use [`closest('div')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) it, will traverse the DOM upwards and find and return the first `div`.

So the full code would be (untested):

```
$('#producer-email').closest('div').append(addSelect);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to target the parent of that parent? And I like your answer, funny thing is the long names were not auto generated. whoever made this website did it ten years ago and they made these naming conventions. Really annoying stepping through their code.

Comment: You could use [`closest('div')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) it, will traverse the DOM upwards and find and return the first `div`.
So the full code would be (untested): `$('#producer-email').closest('div').append(addSelect);`

Comment: That did it, thanks very much. It puts the select in a better position for the user. If you could edit your answer to reflect that I'll mark it.. Both you and Sharlike did answer the questions, is there a way to mark both and have alternative answers?

Comment: @BrandenHam You know you could upvote them if you found them useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `.` in your selector between the two classes:

```
$('#producer_section_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_ .field-row_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_.last_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_' ).append(addSelect);
```

Alternatively you could use the following to grab the last div out of the set:

```
$('#producer_section_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_ .field-row_ns_Z7_MH8C1H40JOBA50AA7D2DGU00G4_:last' ).append(addSelect);
```

Comment: Also an answer, just is messy because of badly named divs but @Sharlike did answer it completely!